# Cannot supress drafts on Hugo build with blogdown

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I generated a new blogdown site using the command:

```
blogdown::new_site()
```

I then added:

```
draft: true
```

to one of the sample blog posts and ran:

```
blogdown::build_site()
```

However, the draft posts still render, like so:

[image: illustration of draft posts getting rendered]

I've tried a few different combinations (e.g, using **draft: yes**; or building directly via hugo), and no matter what I do, the draft posts still get built and rendered - and this happens with files that have either the .md or the .Rmd extension.

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

I should note that I  did not use RStudio but just ran this in the R console on my terminal.

Edit: Here's a GIF to make the issue clearer - when I run `blogdown::build_site()`, the drafts render, but when I run `blogdown::hugo_build()`, the drafts disappear - I suspect this is different from the intended behavior (?)

[image]

Comment: I use draft when I don't want a post deployed to my website but do want to see how it will look by perusing a local copy via serve_site() (I know this isn't exactly what you are doing but may be related)

Comment: Right, I do use serve_site() when I want to preview drafts, but I use deployhq to deploy my site and that simply works by copying out the public/ directory in my repo to the server - so I want to be sure that my local preview is consistent with the public view of my site, if that makes sense. I am in a situation where I can't use Netlify, unfortunately - or I'd be quite happy with the recommended combination of using serve_site() and building on Netlify.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you were previewing your site locally with `blogdown::serve_ste()`, which always shows drafts, as documented in the **blogdown** book: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html. On the same page, I said that you don't need to worry about it if your website is deployed on a server where you run the `hugo` command, such as Netlify (i.e., drafts will not be built).

Comment: Right - I also looked up your response to a related question where you explain the difference between serve_site(), build_site() and hugo_build(). Unfortunately, I seem to be getting this behavior even when I run build_site() - wherein I figure the drafts should not show. 

To recap: I just created a new_site(), edited the YAML headers on one of the posts to make it a draft, and then invoked build_site() - for this sequence, the drafts should not show, right, even on the local preview? 

I'll check if the issue persists when I deploy with Netlify and post back here.

Comment: Okay, another update: I tried running these commands from Rstudio, and it wouldn't let me run blogdown::build_site() - it said some packages are missing (I think it was rstudioapi). With the packages installed, I think this is finally working just as I expected. Phew! I will play around with some more examples and confirm :)

Comment: Sadly, the issue appears to persist in Rstudio - could you please take a quick look at this screen recording whenever you have a chance: https://www.dropbox.com/s/87q1d4aijk62k40/SR.gif?dl=0 - is this the expected behavior?